# how to remove ajax loader from the contact form

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, contacts, loader

I had one contact [form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wr-contactform/) wordpress plugin which loads with [ajax](http://puu.sh/kQfO5/4ec3d200ae.png) so i want to remove that loader type ajax what should be done?

Comment: Do you have a demo installation? I suggest you hide the loader with CSS.

Comment: Iam having it on localhost and I don't want to hide that I want to remove it only.

Comment: Why do you want to disable AJAX processing? Did you look through the plugin settings and the documentation?

Comment: yes no such thing mentioned there.

Can you tell me how to inspect that element in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the element which you want to remove by going to browser.

If chrome you can directly press ctrl+shift+i and windows will open.

Locate that particular loader you want to remove and you will find it wrapped in div or id.

Find that and put it in css code with this command as shown in example.

```
.ajaxloader {display:none;}
#ajaxloader {display:none;}
```

Hope this will works.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the AJAX loader was enclosed with a span tag, so the code looked like this:

```
.ajaxloader span {display:none;}
```